# Making functions react to keypress

Tags: vimscript, buffers, autocompletion, functions

Im very new to vim scripting.
I have the following script in my .vimrc:

- If there is no user input aka I press `<CR>` => go to recent buffer
- If input is 'd' => delete all buffers except for the current one
- Else go to inputted buffer.

```
"Fast buffer switch
function Warp()
  ls
  call inputsave()
  let bufname = input('warp: ')
  call inputrestore()
  if bufname == ""
    b#
  elseif bufname == "d"
    %bd|e#|bd#
  else
    exe "b " . bufname
  endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <C-f> :call Warp()<CR>
```

The `:b`command works so that I dont have to write the full filepath but only a substring of the file name. For example I can navigate to `bar/foo/helloworld.js` with `:b hello`.
However, sometimes file names can overlap which causes `:b` to error out. An intuitive solution to this is to use tab-completion to select the correct file when using `:b` on the command line. However, I dont know how this could be integrated into my function or even if it is possible.
Somethings I noticed:

- `nnoremap <C-f> :b`  allows me to use tab-completion
- `getchar() == 13` allows me to detect `<CR>`
- Maybe something with feedkeys but I dont know if that works with cmdline.
  Some further ideas I have but dont think is possible in simple vim scripting is catching the error so that the user can revise or use tab-completion the file name inputted clashes.

Thank you in advance. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you want to read [`:h :command-complete`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-complete): The idea would be to create a new command ([`:h user-commands`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#user-commands)) `Warp` which will have `-complete=buffer` and which will call your `Warp()` function. This way you can use `:Warp hel<tab>` and you will get the same completion as for `:b hel<tab>`

Comment: @statox Thank you so much. With your advice, I was able to get ```:Warp``` working: [Imgur](https://imgur.com/1aPlvS5). The problem is ```:ls``` no longer works. When I map using ```|```, ```:Warp``` is not invoked as shown in the picture.

Comment: I fixed it! Ended up not needing <bar>. @statox many thanks!

Comment: I didn't have time to answer but it's great you figured it out by yourself. Welcome to our site and congrats on your first question and answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix is to use the third argument of `input`, which is a `{completion}` type (list at `:help :command-completion`):

```
…
const bufname = input('warp: ', '', 'buffer')
…
```

(I used `const` instead of `let`, too.)

Comment: Wow I really like this solution. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing this little script:

```
" --Warp: fast buffer switch
function Warp(...)
  let bufname = a:1
  if bufname == ""
    b#
  else
    if bufname == "d"
      echo("d")
      %bd|e#|bd#
    else
      exe "b " . bufname
    endif
  endif
endfunction
command! -nargs=? -complete=buffer Warp :call Warp(<q-args>)
nnoremap <C-f> :buffers<CR>:Warp
```

The UI isnt as nice as the first iteration because the command `:buffers` stays in the view and `:Warp`  doesnt feel like im filling into input box like `warp:`  but the tab-completion works perfectly.
Many thanks to @statox for helping me out.
Any advice for extending my script will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some nits: `bufname == ""` could be written `empty(bufname)`; I prefer to spell out commands (so `buffer #`, `%bdelete`, `edit #`, `bdelete#`, etc.); `execute` automatically adds a single space between arguments, so `execute 'buffer' bufname` is enough; `elseif` is valid, so you can save yourself some nesting

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you very much for taking the time, Ill make these changes.